# Gradient calculation using chain rule

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Question:**

Use the chain rule to show that the gradient of the function:
$$
h(\sigma)=\frac{1}{2}\|f(\sigma)-y\|^{2}
$$
is:
$$
(f(\sigma)-y)^{T} \nabla f
$$

---

**My Take:**

By the chain rule I can tell that:
$$
\left(h\circ f\right)'\left(x\right)=\left(\left(h'\circ f\right)\cdot f'\right)\left(x\right)=h'\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\cdot f'\left(x\right)\Longrightarrow\frac{dh}{dx}=\frac{dh}{df}\cdot\frac{df}{dx}
$$
So that:
$$
\nabla h=\frac{\partial h}{\partial\sigma_{i}}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial f}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial\sigma_{i}}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial f}\cdot\nabla f
$$
The thing I miss is how to calculate $\frac{\partial h}{\partial f}$ and get the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable and $y \in \mathbb R^m$. Let's define
$$
F(x) = \frac12 \| f(x) - y \|^2.
$$
Notice that
$F(x) = G(H(x))$ where
$$
H(x) = f(x) - y \quad \text{and} \quad G(u) = \frac12 \| u \|^2.
$$
The derivatives of $G$ and $H$ are
$$
G'(u) = \underbrace{u^T}_{1 \times m} \quad \text{and} \quad H'(x) = \underbrace{f'(x)}_{m \times n}.
$$
By the chain rule,
$$
\underbrace{F'(x)}_{1 \times n} = G'(H(x)) H'(x) = \underbrace{(f(x) - y)^T}_{1 \times m} \underbrace{f'(x)}_{m \times n}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The objective function writes
$h 
= \frac12 \| \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y}\|^{2}$.

Using differential principles,
\begin{eqnarray}
dh 
&=& \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y}:d\mathbf{f} \\
&=& \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y}:\mathbf{J}_f d\mathbf{x} \\
&=& \mathbf{J}_f^T 
\left[ \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{y} \right]: d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray}
The gradient is the left term in the Frobenius inner product and
$\mathbf{J}_f$ is the Jacobian matrix.